# how to get dynamically generated table td input value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically generated table like below

[image]

this is the code that generate this table

```js
function pullInventory(data) {

    var container = document.getElementById('inventoryContainer')
 
    var index = 0;
 
 
    console.log(index)
    data.forEach(function(awardsSnap) {
        index ++;
         // console.log(awardsSnap, index)
        var awardItem = awardsSnap.val()

        // Attach an asynchronous callback to rea

        var NSNcard = `
        
                <tr>
                    <td class="serial">${awardItem.NSN}</td>
               
                    <td> ${awardItem.Nomenclature} </td>
                    <td>   ${awardItem.Awarddate} </td> 
                    <td> ${awardItem.Awardid} </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="i.e. 100 EA" class="form-control" value="" id="qty${index}"style="width: 110px;">

                     </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="i.e. $9.23 " class="form-control" value="" style="width: 110px;">
                    </td> 
                   
                </tr>

                    `;
        container.innerHTML += NSNcard;
 
    });

}
```

I want to get all the user entered quantity and price on a button click so I use this

```js
document.querySelector("#savebtn").addEventListener("click", e => {

    var rows = document.getElementById("WelcomeTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
   saveInventory(rows);
});

function saveInventory(rows) {
  const columnHeader = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".table th"),
    th => {
      return th.innerHTML;
    }
  );

  const tableContent = Object.values(
    document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody tr")
  ).map(tr => {
    const tableRow = Object.values(tr.querySelectorAll("td")).reduce(
      (accum, curr, i) => {
        const obj = { ...accum };
        obj[columnHeader[i]] = curr.innerHTML.trim();
 
            console.log(accum, curr, i)

        return obj;
      },
      {}
    );
    return tableRow;
  });
  

}
```

everything works fine except that the two input column in the table above does not detect user input. I'm not able to get the quantity and price value entered.

```
   Award Date: "08-23-2012"
  
   Award#: "SP452013D0055"
  
   NSN: "S222V00004789"
   
   Nomenclature: " BATTERIES, NICKEL-CADMIUM"
   
   Quantity: "<input type="text" placeholder="i.e. 100 EA" class="form-control" value="" id="qty18" style="width: 110px;">"
   
   Unit-Price: "<input type="text" placeholder="i.e. $9.23 " class="form-control" value="" style="width: 110px;">"
```

I tried this and other things but they output undefine

obj[columnHeader[4]]=curr.val();
obj[columnHeader[4]]=curr.value;

how could i get the enetered quantity and price from the dynamic table?

Comment: Please edit your question and create ONE snippet that actually runs showing a [mcve]

Comment: What kind of object do you pass to pullInventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing something like this:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let targetTable = document.getElementById('target-table');
  let targetTableRows = targetTable.rows;
  let tableHeaders = targetTableRows[0];
  
  // start from the second row as the first one only contains the table's headers
  for(let i = 1; i < targetTableRows.length; i++){
    // loop over the contents of each row
    for(let j = 0; j < targetTableRows[i].cells.length; j++){
      // something we could use to identify a given item
      let currColumn = tableHeaders.cells[j].innerHTML;
      // the current <td> element
      let currData = targetTableRows[i].cells[j];
      // the input field in the row
      let currDataInput = currData.querySelector('input');
      
      // is the current <td> element containing an input field? print its value.
      // Otherwise, print whatever is insside
      currDataInput ? console.log(`${currColumn}: ${currDataInput.value}`) 
        : console.log(`${currColumn}: ${currData.innerHTML}`); 
    }
  }
  
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table" id="target-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Person #</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="01-quantity" id="value-01"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="01-price" id="value-01-2"></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="02-quantity" id="value-02"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="02-price" id="value-02-2"></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="03-quantity" id="value-03"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="03-price" id="value-03-2"></td>     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What is done in the example above should also work for your specific case.

Also, here's a [working exmaple](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/gQOoJK) :)

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT! Thank You my friend

Answer (score 1):

`val()` is jQuery method. You'll need to use `.value` in JavaScript.

Comment: Not only that, but data seems to be an array - if it is not an array of inputs, then .value will also not work unless the object has a ["value"] attribute

Answer (score 0):

obj[columnHeader[i]] = curr.innerHTML.trim();

innerHtml.trim returns only tag having direct child with text in it. In your code last two td having an input as child.
so in that case you need to check 'curr' having a child available. if there is a child available and its tagName is input, then you have to use childs value.

for example

```
obj[columnHeader[i]] = curr.children.length && curr.children[0].tagName=="INPUT" ? curr.children[0].value : curr.innerHTML.trim();
```

the above condition can be check and assign to a variable before it is assigned to key

Comment: it still return undefine for both input fields

Comment: can you try using 
obj[columnHeader[i]] = curr.children.length && curr.children[0].tagName=="INPUT" ? curr.children[0].value : curr.innerHTML.trim();